# pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function preprocessor at 0x109217488>: it's not found as __main__.preprocessor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

I need to store a machine learning classifier that I developed using sklearn. I am using joblib package for this. Here is how I do it:

```
from sklearn.externals improt joblib

#clf is defined above
joblib.dump(clf,'test.clf')
```

I am having the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "svm_clf.py", line 333, in <module>
  my_svm_classifier(get_best_model(), X, y, name="svm pos vs neg", plot=True)
  File "svm_clf.py", line 300, in my_svm_classifier
    joblib.dump(clf, 'neg.clf')
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 369, in dump pickler.dump(value)

...
...
...

pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function preprocessor at 0x108301488>: it's not found as \__main\__.preprocessor
```

Any help?

Comment: Did you define a function named `preprocessor` as a local function by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I have my dear. It was a kind of helper. It was defined inside a function---basically, a sub function. I moved it up to avoid being a sub function and seems working fine. Thanks.

Comment: Well, in fact that didn't help. I am having two errors: (1) pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function my_preprocessor at 0x1089a4578>: it's not the same object as\ __main\__.preprocessor. This error is raised when I made 'preprocessor' a sub function. When I make this function global, I got the following error while loading the module: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'preprocessor'

Comment: `__main__` is not treated as first class module, when pickling by reference… thus, if the function is in main, and pickle refers to the function by name, then you will get a `PicklingError`.  You should try `dill` or `cloudpickle`, which are better serializers, and treat `__main__` like a first class citizen.  If you take the `dill` master on github, and just say `import dill`, it will override normal pickling behavior in `pickle`. `dill` and `cloudpickle` also can (generally) pickle all objects that your function depends on, and take them with the pickle (either by source or by reference).

Comment: Or you could move the function to a separate file ;)